# trying to understand Gundb (nodejs application) for my study

Tags: javascript, node.js, vercel, gun

For my study I'm trying to use Gun to store the date for my app.

I thought it would be useful to first use one location to host my data, get it up and running and then introduce the peer connectivity.

Now my first question would be: is this way of thinking correct?

Then, how would I go about deploying to something now now.sh

I'm not looking for a one line solution, more some more pointers in to change my way of thinking. Although I *think* I understand the appeal of decentralized data I would love to hear if I am correct/wrong.

Kind regards,

Daneel

Answer (score 1):

@a-daneel yes, you are correct. You can start with 0, 1, or Many connections, then always add or subtract more later.

As for `now` I don't use it myself personally, but you should follow whatever instructions they provide on deploying.

If you want to find other like-minded people to chat with, do join our discussion chat room on http://chat.gun.eco ! :) Super super super friendly and helpful people there.